# Можно ли указать в CSS селекторе на нужный класс

Tags: java, selenium

Мне нужно обратиться к фильтрам на сайте - пример: ширина, высота, длина мебели. В тесте использую цикл, чтобы нашелся нужный фильтр.
Чтобы дойти до нужного элемента пишу что-то вроде:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#catalog > form > div:nth-of-type(" + i + ") > div");
```

Фильтры разные, по конструкции в *HTML* схожи, но есть 1 тип фильтра который не подходит, и достучаться до него не могу - получая ожидаемую ошибку `No Such Element`.

Вопрос: есть какой-то аналог, или можно (вроде нет) напрямую указать искомый класс?

Пример :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#catalog > form > div:nth-of-type(" + i + ") > div.class="\Искомый класс"\ ");
```

Comment: Наверное, просто div.искомый класс

Comment: @humster_spb, максимально забыл про это :D спасибо

Answer (score 1):

`"div.class_name"` - элементы div с атрибутом `class=class_name`. То же самое, но длиннее: `"div[class=class_name]"`

`".class_name"` -  все элементы с атрибутом `class=class_name`. Или `"[class=class_name]"`

Шпаргалка по CSS селекторам - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp